# $GL_{n}(Q_{p})$ of $n$ by $n$ matrices with entries in the field $Q_{p}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How could you show that the space $GL_{n}(Q_{p})$ of $n$ by $n$ matrices with entries in the field $Q_{p}$ is open?

I want to determine this to determine that  $GL_{n}(Q_{p})$ is locally compact. This is correct?

Comment: A space isn't open, it is open *in* another space.

Comment: It is open in the space of all $n\times n$ matrices, since it is the inverse image $\det^{-1}(\mathbb Q_p\setminus\{0\})$ and $\mathbb Q_p\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\det$ is continuous.

Comment: Have your shown the space of all $n\times n$ matrices is locally compact?

Comment: No, I have not proved that.